# Is it possible to list time in 24h format in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I'm kinda new with react and I wanna ask, is it possible to list time in 24h format as a grid?

Like:

```
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
```

and so on...There are no exceptions, it should show all.

Haven't found any component or internal feature for this.

Would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: If you just want to render 24 numbers you don't need a special component, `div` should do, no?

Comment: Well, I can just make an array of numbers and def it, but like might be there is already a solution inside which could be used :)

Comment: In React you can make a function that returns an array of 24 divs, I don't think anyone released a library to do just that yet ,you can be the fist! :0)

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova Could you give me an advice on how to do that please? :)

Comment: What's your requirements? Just literary print numbers? what are you going to do with them?

Comment: Well, they will be used as checkboxes, so users could check them. They will be pushed to the backend as an array of 2, i mean if a person selects 4 different times, then there will be 2 different arrays with 2 values in each array. But yeah, I should show them frist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a checkbox to each and remember selection in the state but the bare minimum will be something like

```
const MyClock = React.memo(() => {
 const clock=[]
 for(let i=0; i<24; i++)
   clock.push( <li key={i}>{(i+":00").padStart(5,"0")}</li>);
 return clock;
});
```